# How to add Web Interface to C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, mobile

I have an existing C# windows application, however I would like to be able to control the application using a mobile device - eg. iPhone / Android / WebOS device. How would I go about exposing the application to these devices?

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Comment: If I take the webos as a specific example, I want to create a webos application that can be used to control / call specific functions within my C# application. I'd like some advice on how to expose these functions to such a javascript application.

Comment: It is a diary / time management application - setting of reminders / tasks. I'd like to be able to add tasks / reminders from the mobile app when the c# application is running but I may be in a different room etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would vote WCF.  We just added a web interface to a very large API and it was easy and worked great.